# Windows 10 C: drive not listed as system drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bootloader

When I installed windows when upgrading my PC, I had the old windows SSD plugged in, which blue screens on boot due to mismatched motherboard files as far as i can tell. I then installed Windows to my M.2 NVME and now use that windows installation. In the disk management window, the old SSD shows as Disk 0 Healthy (System, active, primary partition) and the new SSD (which is listed as the C: drive and has the windows icon next to it in file explorer) shows as Disk 3 Healthy (Boot, Page File, Active, Crash Dump, Primary Partition). When I disconnected the old SSD and booted from the new one, I got an error that said no operating system was found.

I'd like to be able to have my new SSD labeled as the system disk and not be dependent on the old SSD for the PC to boot.

Comment: What happens if you remove the old SSD and then start without it?  Will it start?

Comment: You need to update the BCD store, and if the old SSD is still attached, you need to select no if the last `BootRec` command lists a Windows install on that drive. Boot to WinRE: _Settings_ → _Update & Security_ → _Recovery_ → _Advanced Startup_ → _Restart Now_ → _Advanced_ → _Troubleshooting_ → _Command Prompt_ → If SSD is still attached, ascertain it's drive letter: `DiskPart` → `lis vol` → `exit` → Rebuild BCD Store: `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD` → Close the terminal and _Continue to Windows_

Comment: When I remove the old SSD and boot to the new SSD, I get an error saying no operating system is found.